# By default, the left ALT key drags and moves windows. How can I get rid of that?

Tags: shortcut-keys

It competes with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> behavior in Photoshop, so I want the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to do nothing.

Comment: I don't exactly can figure out how this behaviour can compete with the ALT behaviour in photoshop, but if you could install Photoshop under wine I would appreciate if you point me to a place where to find a how to. If you are using Photoshop in a virtual machine (Virtualbox) you may be interested in the "Seamless mode" which may help you to fix this issue.

Comment: I installed Photoshop using "Play On Linux" and it works fine. The alt key is used in Photoshop  to duplicate a selection. Quite handy.

Comment: Gimp and inkscape also use the Alt key for things

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change it from <kbd>Alt</kbd> to <kbd>Super</kbd> and vice-versa. Go to *System ➜ Preferences ➜ Windows* and in the Windows Preferences Choose which "Movement Key" you wish to use.

A screenshot to illustrate is placed here:

[image]

Additionally, if you are using compiz, you can change which key bindings you wish to use in order to "Initiate Window Move" when the "Enable Move Window" plugin is in use.

Here is a screenshot to illustrate what I say in the above words:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. The "ALT" to "SUPER" trick works perfectly !

Comment: I couldn't find this, is it changed in newer versions of ubuntu? I'm on 15

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd> in Photoshop. I have tried this in Photoshop under VirtualBox machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the X key from command line (Terminal):

Gnome 2 (Ubuntu 11.10)

```
sudo apt-get install -y gconf2
gconftool-2 -t str --set /apps/metacity/general/mouse_button_modifier '<Super>'
```

Gnome 3 (Ubuntu 13.04)

```
sudo apt-get install -y libglib2.0-bin
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier '<Super>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Xfwm4 window manager = Xubuntu 16.04 = Xfce mouse menu;

1. application = Window Manager Tweaks;
2. tab = Accessibility;
3. firstLine = Key used to grab and move windows: Super (make your choice);

/* LibreOffice uses Alt-drag to move columns and rows. Window manager Xfwm4 interprets an Alt-drag before LibreOffice if assigned. */

Answer (score 0):

For `XFCE` `DE` you change it from `Window Manager Tweaks`

[image]